# Counting elements of order 6 in $D_{12} \times Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, direct-product

Actually I know how to count number of elements of particular order from direct product .But In this my counting is not matches with answer so I wanted to know where is my mistake lies .
 I wanted to Count elements of order 6 in $D_{12} \times Z_2$ 
 
$6=3 \times 2=6\times 1$

There are 2 elements of order 3 in $D_{12}$ and $1$ element in $Z_2$ Similarly there are 2 elements of order 6  in $D_{12}$ and for 6 we can chose 1 or 2 as gcd remain 6 so we have 2 elements from $Z_2$ so 2*2+2=6 choices are available but answer is 4 where is my mistake lie? Any Help will be appreciated [image]

Comment: When you say "1 element in $\Bbb{Z}_2$", you mean "1 element **of order 2** in $\Bbb{Z}_2$". Apart from that little detail, your argument looks fine to me. Where were you told that the answer was 4?

Comment: It is problem in Contemporary abstract algebra By J F Gallian chapter 8 problem 41 and solution is provided in Solution manual .Thanks for Reply

Comment: The question is asking you to prove that $D_3 \oplus D_4$ and $D_{12} \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ are not isomorphic and the solution in the book suggests counting elements of order $6$. (Gallian's $D_n$ is the dihedral group with $2n$ elements.) I get 4 for $D_3 \oplus D_4$  and 6 (like you) for $D_{12} \times \Bbb{Z}_2$, so these two groups are not isomorphic. I think your solution manual is wrong.

Comment: Correction: I now think 10 is right for $D_3 \oplus D_4$, but I still think your solution manual is wrong and you are right about $D_{12}\times \Bbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your count is correct!

To find the number of elements of order $6$ in $D_{12} \times \Bbb{Z}_2$, we have $$6=\vert (a,b) \vert =\text{lcm}\;\{\vert a \vert, \vert b \vert\}$$

so we have three cases:

Case i): $\vert a \vert =6$ and $\vert b \vert=1$

Case ii): $\vert a \vert =6$ and $\vert b \vert=2$

Case iii): $\vert a \vert =3$ and $\vert b \vert=2$

By this result
 " If $d$ is a positive integer, $d \neq 2$ and $d \vert n$, then the number of elements of order $d$ in $D_n$ is $\phi(d)$", each cases have two choices and hence totally we have six candidates!